# Генерация больших массивов неодинаковых чисел

Tags: python, python-3.x, оптимизация

Предположим, мне нужно создать огромный (порядка миллиона) список случайных чисел. Но не просто случайных чисел, а неодинаковых случайных чисел. Вопрос в следующем: как сделать это наиболее быстрым способом?

Варианты:

1: (проверка каждого элемента перед добавлением)

```
import random
nums = []
for i in range(10 ** 6):
    while True:
        x = random.random()
        if nums.find() + 1:
            nums.append(x)
            break
        else:
            continue
```

2: (проверка после генерации всего списка)

```
import random
while True:
    for i in range(10 ** 6):
        nums.append(random.random())
    if list(set(nums)) == nums: break
    else: continue
```

3: (варварский ☺)

```
import random
nums = []
x = random.random()
for i in range(10 ** 6):
    nums.append(x * i)
```

Может, есть и какой-то еще вариант с применениями специальных методов, — возможно из других модулей — предназначенных специально для генерации неодинаковых чисел. Если таковой имеется, подскажите его, пожалуйста.

Так какой вариант лучше? Или имеется более быстрый алгоритм?

Comment: Первые две идеи ок, но реализация  плохая в обоих случаях.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8505754/15035314

Comment: @АлексейР, numpy, к сожалению, не входит в состав стандартной библиотеки питона, а у меня интересуют только методы из стандартной библиотеки.

Comment: @Эникейщик, а чем плоха реализация? Можете объяснить, что именно в ней не так?

Comment: Миллион - это не огромный. Огромный - это когда список не помещается в память.

Comment: Например, во-втором случае вероятность того, что в списке будет именно миллион элементов очень мала. И если там выпадет хотя бы два одинаковых числа, то цикл вообще никогда не завершится. Не говоря уже о том, что порядок элементов после ``list(set(nums))`` вряд ли будет совпадать с исходным.

Comment: @Эникейщик, списки ж по ссылке сравниваются, так что там всегда false независимо от вероятностей.

Comment: Точно, что вещественные числа нужны?

Comment: @Эникейщик, стоп, а вещественные случайные числа вообще могут повторяться в нормальной ситуации? Это не будет означать, что мы вытрясли весь диапазон случайных чисел и новое вообще не можем получить?

Comment: @Эникейщик, https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoMS8lP5eLKy2/SCFeITMPJJCeqmFoYKBpxaWgUFCUmVeikZOap1GcWqIBUawHoTQ0FTA1gYAmEPz/DwA

Comment: @Qwertiy random.random() знаков 16-17 после запятой выдаёт, так что запас для миллиона достаточный.

Comment: @Qwertiy, списки в Питоне сравниваются по содержимому, в отличие от JavaScript.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, упс. Я думал, только tuple по содержимому. Запомню)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

##### Первый вариант

Человек может догадаться что значит `if nums.find() + 1:`, компилятор - нет. В выражении не упоминается `x`, список в питоне не имеет метода `find`. Если предположить, что подразумевалось `if x not in nums:`, то способ рабочий. На моём компьютере он выполнится за полтора часа.

##### Второй вариант

Если условие `if list(set(nums)) == nums:` окажется истинным, то мы действительно получим список из миллиона уникальных чисел в `nums`. К сожалению комбинация `list(set(...))` перемешивает свой аргумент определённым образом. Равенство выполнится если все числа уникальны **и их порядок в `nums` совпадёт с результатом `list(set(...))`**. Какова вероятность этого события? *1 / (10<sup>6</sup>!) ≈ 10<sup>-5565709</sup>*. Одна итерация цикла занимает примерно секунду. До получения результата нужно будет подождать около *10<sup>5565709</sup>* секунд. Возраст вселенной - *10<sup>18</sup>* секунд. Ждать придётся долго. Но это только полбеды. Даже если бы у нас было в запасе это время, нужная комбинация не будет сгенерирована, скорее всего. Причину я опущу чтобы не утомлять вас. Вердикт - способ не рабочий.

Если заменить условие на `if len(set(nums)) == 10 ** 6:` то способ окажется рабочим и очень быстрым - будет работать около секунды.

##### Третий вариант

Числа не случайные. Если вас такая случайность устраивает - хорошо. Но внимательный наблюдатель заметит что числа растут, следуют с определённым интервалом. Короче - слишком заметны недостатки.

#### Решения

Примерно 0.69 секунды.

```
import random

s = set()
while len(s) < 1_000_000:
    s.add(random.random())
l = list(s)
```

Из них 0.16с уходит на собственно генерацию. Остальные 0.53с - работа с множеством.

Этот вариант чуть быстрее - 0.6с:

```
import random

size = 1_000_000
s = set()
while len(s) < size:
    s.update(random.random() for _ in range(size - len(s)))
l = list(s)
```

Ещё быстрее - 0.55c:

```
import random

size = 1_000_000
s = set(random.random() for _ in range(size))
while len(s) < size:
    s.update(random.random() for _ in range(size - len(s)))
l = list(s)
```

Часто ли во втором примере потребуется больше одной итерации? Часто ли в последнем примере понадобится заходить в цикл? На оба вопроса ответ один: вероятность что потребуется дополнять множество равна *6·10<sup>-5</sup>*. Другими словами - редко. Если мой компьютер в цикле будет генерировать наборы случайных чисел, ему понадобится дополнять набор в среднем раз в два с половиной часа.

**P.S.** Честно говоря, первый вариант мне нравиться больше. Просто и достаточно быстро.

**P.P.S.** Более интересная задача возникнет если добавить ограничение на память при генерации.

Comment: Скажите, а почему вы между импортом и кодом вставляете две пустые строчки? По стандартам вроде полагается одна. Или я путаю?

Comment: @Глеб, вы правы, ничего не путаете. Я неправильно запомнил и все блоки в глобальной области отделял двумя строками. ПЕП8 этого не требует. Поправил на одну строку. Спасибо!

Comment: Кстати, а есть причины считать, что вещественные числа вообще могут повторяться? Эксперимент говорит, что всё получается за первую генерацию: https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoMS8lP5eLKy2/SCFeITMPJJCeqmFoYKBpxaWgUFCUmVeikZOap1GcWqIBUawHoTQ0FTA1gYAmEPz/DwA. Не означает ли повтор числа то, что мы выгребли весь возможный диапазон случайных чисел и новое вообще не можем получить? Впрочем, с проверкой и циклом надёжнее, по крайней мере в том плане, что если уж код завершится, то мы точно будем иметь нужное количество чисел.

Comment: @Qwertiy, всё так и есть. В последнем варианте вероятность зайти в цикл очень низкая. Но для корректности сделано так. Можно было бы генерировать список без проверки. Не думаю что тестами такой "дефект" ловится.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, я просто не в курсе, что гарантирует random. Если там только одно значение в состоянии, то получится, что после первого повтора будет повторяться всё и в том же порядке. Но я не знаю ничего про его внутренности в питоне.

Comment: @Qwertiy, random как раз гарантирует что цикла не будет. То есть, у генератора конечное количество состояний и в этом смысле цикл будет. Но его длина скорее всего 2^512. Так что отдельные вещественные числа (которых 2^53) будут повторяться, но повторения всей последовательности нам не дождаться.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, прикольно. Я как раз попробовал цикл дождаться - не видно: https://tio.run/##bY7BCsMgEETv@xXTQyFSkYTeCn5MIQ0uJCpqaPx6Y2NOoXvZndkHMz4n4@yzFF68CwnhbUe30KlijkQb9GmrtjpB@Y/H1RuIvobnz/WJm8b2IoDxOKh6TVXcMfRtoDX6HwH4wDZ1LA5RK6iYRrcmNc1rNDWIGrBJZAmW1yxRyg4.

Comment: @Qwertiy, прежде чем делать такие попытки, надо оценить МО ожидания. Технически это задача о "днях рождения в классе".

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, неа, чтобы было о днях рождения, надо все результаты сохранять, а я сохранил только один именно в расчёте на цикл. Если у дней рождений матожидание sqrt(n), то в моём случае просто n.

Comment: @Qwertiy, вероятность найти совпадающую пару в миллионе чисел - *0.00006*. Для 111 миллионов - около *0.5*. Да, ваш тест про другое.

Answer (score 3):

Вероятно, вам подойдёт [random.sample()](https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-random-python/funktsija-random-sample/)

```
import random

print([x/1000 for x in random.sample(range(1000), 10)])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import uuid

s=[uuid.uuid4().int for i in range(1_000_000)]
l=list(set(s))
```

---

```
...
19338761825466288640265314643851179312
178303052562301544546569716401959751820
147718195392286393968890593237377029069
196091551904263230486818310589002110116
42826159964564327211771179483953807288
297151613728264239240276251569460736275
...
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html

Answer (score 2):

Что-то никто не написал про перемешивание с помощью `shuffle`. Ну, тогда напишу я.

Чистый питон:

```py
from random import shuffle

n = 1_000_000
lst = [i/(n+1) for i in range(n)]
shuffle(lst)
```

Долго - порядка 0.75с.

Но ведь у нас есть `Numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np

n = 1_000_000
arr = np.arange(n) / (n+1)
np.random.shuffle(arr)
```

Быстро - около 30мс в `Google Colab`.