# Как в Python сгенерировать многозначное число, чтобы цифры в нем не повторялись?

Tags: python, случайные-числа, числа

Нужно, чтобы программа генерировала четырехзначное число, в котором цифры не будут повторяться. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Недавно задавал чем-то схожий вопрос: [Генерация больших массивов неодинаковых чисел](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1539391/Генерация-больших-массивов-неодинаковых-чисел)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import itertools
print(*list(map(lambda x:''.join(map(str,x)),itertools.permutations([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 4))))
```

---

```
import itertools
print(*(list(filter(lambda y:y if y[0] != '0' else '', map (lambda x:''.join(map(str,x)),itertools.permutations([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 4))))))
```

Можно нули подфильтровать.

Comment: этот способ я и хотел) в одну строку с помощью этого модуля) спс огромное!

Comment: Лидирующие нули - нормально?

Comment: В задании не оговорено, неизвестно.

Comment: `0123` - традиционно четырёхзначным числом не называется.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy в задании я действительно не оговорил, но нули эти можно поправить после. Я искал именно эту концепцию

Comment: Тогда уберите из вопроса термин "число". То что вы ищете не числа, а комбинации цифр.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy не, вопрос верный, именно числа) Можно будет подправить этот код, чтобы без нулей. Я это имел в виду

Comment: вооот, я ж говорю, можно нули убрать. Способ отличный!

Comment: Что-то сложновато?

Comment: Судя по тому, какое решение вы отметили как ответ, вы неточно сформировали вопрос.
Вам наверное нужен список  **всех** четырехзначных чисел без повторений в наборе его цифр.
Если так, то уточняйте текст запроса. А то большинство -как и я- поняло текст так, как вы его написали,  ане так, как вы думали ))))))

Answer (score 1):

Можно реализовать так:

```py
import random

digits = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
random.shuffle(digits)
number = ''

for i in digits[:4]:number += str(i)

print(number)
```

**Внимание:**
То, что цифры в числе не повторяются снижает возможное количество комбинаций с **10 000** до **5 040**

**UPD:**

В случае, если число начинается с нуля, то добавляем к нему тысячу, так избавимся от трёхзначных значений, когда переводим `str` в `int`

```py
import random

digits = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
random.shuffle(digits)
number = ''

for i in digits[:4]:number += str(i)

number = int(number)
if number < 1000:
    number += 1000

print(number)
```

**Внимание:**
Теперь количество комбинаций составляет **4536**

Comment: `0123` точно четырёхзначное?

Comment: тут получаются строки, а не числа. А если полученную строку конвертировать в число, то не факт, что оно окажется четырехзначным.

Comment: Уфф, не учёл этого

Answer (score 1):

Перебираем все четырёхзначные числа, отбираем те у которых все цифры различные:

```
result = [x for x in range(1000, 10000) if len(set(str(x))) == 4]
```

**P.S.** Способ не самый эффективный, можно перебор сделать лучше. Но он простой и быстрый на практике. Зачем искать что-то сложнее?

Comment: Способ просто немного "нелогичный" и действительно не очень эффективный. Мне хотелось, чтобы программа могла генерировать исключительно числа, состоящие из уникальных цифр, а не проверяла на эту уникальность. Чтобы было как в примере у @WTFisGoingOn. А так да, в принципе способ простой и легко применимый на практике)

Answer (score 1):

[tio.run](https://tio.run/##LYzLCoAgEEX38xWzawSpJFoU1L8IvYzUwVzY15tBZ3UPXA4/8fCuy9lY9iFi0G7xFiDhhMZFqqr69MaR1Ux3DPI/1Le2fK1UbF9JtUJiLwpgNkw441AYy2qaCVULwOGLJZHzCw)

```
import random

x = int(''.join(map(str, random.sample(range(10), 5))))
if x > 9999: x //= 10

print(x)
```

Пятая цифра нужна чтобы избежать проблем с лидирующим нулём.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, так короче и однообразнее.  По крайней мере без лишних проверок и делений.  Благодарю @MBo  за указание на неточность. Правилиный код:

```
from random import sample

digits = list('0123456789')

first_digit = sample(digits[1:], 1)   # список из одной цифры-символа
digits.remove(first_digit[0])
x = "".join(first_digit + sample(digits, 3))
```

про скорость не скажу, но все равно лучше, чем в цикле приклеивать по одному символу.
Здесь первый список состоит из одного символа-цифры, причем предварительно нарезкой отбросили ноль. Второй список - выборка трех неповторяющихся чисел с возможным нулем. Складываем два списка и результирующий список склеиваем.
Добавьте `int()`. Если он нужен.

Используя списки, можно сделать на одну строчку короче:

```
digits = '123456789'
first_digit = sample(digits, 1)   # список из одной цифры-символа
x = "".join(first_digit + sample(list(set(digits) - set(first_digit) | {'0'}), 3))
```

Comment: ага, спасибо. пойду поправлю....

Comment: В строчке ``digits = list('0123456789')`` нет необходимости. Любая строка уже сама по себе список.

Comment: @Эникейщик  - Вы заблуждаетесь.  При попытке удалить из строчки вы получите `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'remove'`

Comment: Это не отменяет того, что без строчки ``digits = list('0123456789')`` можно обойтись. Список в том смысле, что можно к буквам строки обращаться как к элементам списка. А не в смысле, что у строки есть те же методы, что и у списка. Вы создаете из строки список, с которым потом производите ровно одну операцию. Можно просто сразу вписать один раз строчку с 0, один раз без него. Можете заменить remove на replace(first_digit, "") если хочется.

Comment: а можно написать один раз list.
Утверждение **Любая строка уже сама по себе список** для моего уха неприемлимо.

Comment: list в данном случае - лишняя операция, не дающая ничего,

Comment: @Эникейщик она создает список, из которого позже я на месте удаляю нужный ненужный элемент, используя метод списка `digits.remove(first_digit[0])`

Comment: ну можно еще вместо символов использовать числа от 48 до 57 и конвертировать ascii код в символ на месте, раз уж вам так нравится гонять туда-сюда типы данных...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149022/discussion-between-vasyl-kolomiets-and-).